# dynamically resized overlay image with resizable base image and automatic overlay position recalculation

Tags: css, image, overlay, css-position

Is it possible to achieve all five of these requirements? The last is not least.

```
1) an overlay image is placed above a base image
 (e.g. push pin at specified intersection on a city map)

2) the city map can be dynamically resized by the user in the browser window
 (the base image content is static -- i.e. resizing does not include more or less of the city)

3) the size of the push-pin is proportional to the size of the city map 
(the bigger the city map, the bigger the push-pin; the smaller the city map, 
the smaller the push-pin)

4) as the city map's size changes, the push pin's location remains accurate

5) The developer does not have to recalculate the pin's location when map's size changes
```